# Changing third-party websites on android device without browser extensions available

Tags: browser, proxy, dns, https, javascript

I'm searching a way on how to change behavior of some website in mobile browser.

For example:

- Remove annoing Ad (specific one)
- Change some elements on a website, to make it easier to read on small screen (change some css)
- Make site measure how much time I've spent on it, and "block" me from using it more time per day than I've configured.

On desktop browser I'm usually solving this tasks by using extensions like TamperMonkey/GreasyMonkey (which allows me to add custom JavaScript code to page and do what I want on the page), StayFocusd (to limit distractions) and so on.

But most of mobile browsers doesn't have extensions (and it's understandable because they often writen poorly and could eat too much CPU on not-so-powerfull device).

To be honest, Firefox for Android has addons but there are very few. Just adblocking, privacy and some bugfixing extensions. No TamperMonkey/GreasyMonkey analog.

Also, I know, that UCBrowser has it's extension store, but my Chineese is bad, and the store is all on Chinesse :)

**I came to the folowing idea:**

1. Setup my own DNS server and configure my Android to use it (now it's possible without root)
2. Setup my own squid proxy server
3. Create self-signed SSL-certificate and add it to my Android's certificates storage.
4. For sites where I want to make some augmentations, my DNS should give IP-address of my squid-proxy (which is using my self-signed cert or generating cerificated for needed sites, signed by my self-created authority certificate)
5. The proxy should be loading the real site, and patch it's html files, adding my JavaScript file into it.
6. So I would be able to change parts of the sites, removing ads, measure time spend and so on. Everything is possible!

I have knowledge and skills to make all of the described steps (or it seems so), **BUT!** I don't have enough free time.

I want to know, maybe there are something like this implemented in a single service?

Or maybe you could direct me to some easier solution of the problem?

Comment: You have [Tamper monkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/tampermonkey/) and [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) as Firefox add-ons. I use Tamper monkey when required. Why not use them?

Comment: Kiwi browser supports all chrome extensions

Comment: beeshyams thank you, You're right, now then I've digged deeper inside addons menu in mobile Firefox I've found TamperMonkey.

Comment: Second problem: it would be best if solution could be applied to any browser because one of the goal is to limit time, spent on distracting websites. So if Firefox with TamperMonkey and JS banned me from visiting some website, I just could open it in Chrome, or Opera, or Vivaldi (I have all of them for mobile website development and debugging).